# Urllib2.urlopen and request freezes

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, get, httprequest

Edit:I have found that i made a mistake, because the cause of the error wasn't urllib but nltk, which wasn't able to process a long string which came from this exact page. Sorry for this one.

I do not know why, but this no matter if I use Urllib2.urlopen or request when I come across a specific url.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('SomeURL')
print html = r.text
```

Here is its behavior.
1) When I go thought a loop of 200 urls it freezes each time at that exactly the same URL. It stays here for hours if i do not terminate program.
2) When u try with just example of the code outside of the loop it works.
3) If i blacklist just this url it goes through the loop without problems.

It actually doesn't return any kind of error code and it work good outside of loop and also timeout is set but it doesn't do anything. It still hangs for an indefinite time.

So is there any other way to forcefully stop the http get request after a certain time, because the timeout doesn't work. Is there any other library other than urllib2 and request that could do the job, and that follows timeout limits?

```
for i in range(0,mincount):
    code(call the request for urlist[i]) 
    It always works but freezes only when I request this site. If i had 200 request to yahoo   for example it would work. But when i try go to this particular url i cannot.  
#end
```

edit: It is a standard for cycle and there is not much room for error.

Comment: Try httplib2 https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2

Comment: I am trying the module.

Comment: The `timeout` option works. it may be due to your loop code. can you add loop section of your code. are you using `while` statement on that section?

Comment: httplib2 still doesn't work in the for loop. I cannot even guess what in the loop could cause 3 independent kinds of http requests (urllib2, request and httplib2 not to work) just for one URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply a very slow page; on my system, it takes about 9.7s to load.

If you are trying to run it in a short loop, it would indeed seem to freeze.

You could try something like

```
links = [
    'SomeURL',
    'http://www.google.com/'
]

for link in links:
    try:
        html = requests.get(link, timeout=2.).content
        print("Successfully loaded {}".format(link))
    except requests.Timeout:
        print("Timed out loading {}".format(link))
```

which gave me

```
Timed out loading SomeURL
Successfully loaded http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: I tried loop few times, and each time it didn't get loaded after 1000+ seconds. Does python have problem with ajax sites?

Comment: Actually there seems to only be some kind of bug with the for loop I use. This thing loads in 10 sec for me  as well but it doesn't when it is in loop. It is interesting that yahoo.com and any other site works from the loop but this site doesn't.